# How to disable row as well as column checkboxes except the clicked one in the table using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox, disabled-input

I have tried with the following code. I have done disabling the checkboxes in the row. Now I have a problem disabling the respective column.

Find my HTML and JS code in the snippet below.

## Code snippet

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr')
    .find('input[type=checkbox]').not(this)
    .prop('disabled', this.checked);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="reg_table">
  <tr>
   <th></th>
   <th>8-9</th>
   <th>9-10</th>
   <th>10-11</th>
   <th>11-12</th>
   <th>12-13</th>
   <th>13-14</th>
   <th>14-15</th>
   <th>15-16</th>
   
   
  </tr>

       
  <tr>
   <td>Company name 1</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="1" class="sss" name="Company name 1" value="Company name 1~8-9" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="1" class="sss" name="Company name 1" value="Company name 1~9-10" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="1" class="sss" name="Company name 1" value="Company name 1~10-11" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox"  alt="1" class="sss" name="Company name 1" value="Company name 1~11-12" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="1" class="sss" name="Company name 1" value="Company name 1~12-13" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="1" class="sss" name="Company name 1" value="Company name 1~13-14" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox"  alt="1" class="sss" name="Company name 1" value="Company name 1~14-15" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="1" class="sss" name="Company name 1" value="Company name 1~15-16" /></td>
   
   
   
  </tr>
  
    
  <tr>
   <td>Company name 2</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="2" class="sss" name="Company name 2" value="Company name 2~8-9" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="2" class="sss" name="Company name 2" value="Company name 2~9-10" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="2" class="sss" name="Company name 2" value="Company name 2~10-11" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox"  alt="2" class="sss" name="Company name 2" value="Company name 2~11-12" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="2" class="sss" name="Company name 2" value="Company name 2~12-13" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="2" class="sss" name="Company name 2" value="Company name 2~13-14" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox"  alt="2" class="sss" name="Company name 2" value="Company name 2~14-15" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="2" class="sss" name="Company name 2" value="Company name 2~15-16" /></td>
   
   
   
  </tr>
  
    
  <tr>
   <td>Company name 3</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="3" class="sss" name="Company name 3" value="Company name 3~8-9" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="3" class="sss" name="Company name 3" value="Company name 3~9-10" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="3" class="sss" name="Company name 3" value="Company name 3~10-11" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox"  alt="3" class="sss" name="Company name 3" value="Company name 3~11-12" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="3" class="sss" name="Company name 3" value="Company name 3~12-13" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="3" class="sss" name="Company name 3" value="Company name 3~13-14" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox"  alt="3" class="sss" name="Company name 3" value="Company name 3~14-15" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="3" class="sss" name="Company name 3" value="Company name 3~15-16" /></td>
   
   
   
  </tr>
  
    
  <tr>
   <td>Company name 4</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="4" class="sss" name="Company name 4" value="Company name 4~8-9" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="4" class="sss" name="Company name 4" value="Company name 4~9-10" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="4" class="sss" name="Company name 4" value="Company name 4~10-11" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox"  alt="4" class="sss" name="Company name 4" value="Company name 4~11-12" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="4" class="sss" name="Company name 4" value="Company name 4~12-13" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="4" class="sss" name="Company name 4" value="Company name 4~13-14" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox"  alt="4" class="sss" name="Company name 4" value="Company name 4~14-15" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" alt="4" class="sss" name="Company name 4" value="Company name 4~15-16" /></td>
   
   
   
  </tr>
  
  
  
 </table>
```

Note: I am using `<script  src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: As this is a font-end problem, could you consider making a snippet with your code? (replace the PHP parts by HTML)

Comment: hi Pierre i have replaced PHP code by HTML

Comment: HTML Code contains radio buttons. And your JavaScript contains 'input[type=checkbox]'... Weird!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
    $(this).closest('tr')
    .find('input[type=checkbox]').not(this)
    .attr('disabled', this.checked);


    // Below is the added code
    var tdIndex = $(this).closest('td').index() + 1;
    $('table').find("tr td:nth-of-type(" + tdIndex + ")")
    .find('input[type=checkbox]').not(this)
    .attr('disabled', this.checked);

});
```

Tested locally and works as expected.  Will update for the fiddle.

UPDATE: here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/sq3vrxy1/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the column index of the cell that's clicked in.

> If no argument is passed to the .index() method, the return value is an integer indicating the position of the first element within the jQuery object relative to its sibling elements.

Then you can use `:nth-child` to find all the cells in that column:

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/k8u35ysz/

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function(){
        var td = $(this).closest('td');
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var tbl = $(this).closest('table')

        var idx = td.index();

        tbl
          .find("tr td:nth-child(" + (idx+1) + ")")
          .find("input")
          .not(this)
          .prop('disabled', this.checked);

        tr
          .find('input[type=checkbox]')
          .not(this)
          .prop('disabled', this.checked);
```

(the question's code used `radio` but required an option to untick, so changed to checkbox)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    //This will disable all the checkboxes in a table.
    $('.reg_table input[type=checkbox]').attr('disabled', true);

    //This will enable the selected checkbox and set it to selected.
    $(this).attr('disabled', false);
    this.checked = true;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For columns, you’ll need to get the column index.

So… something like that

```
var cell = $(this).closest('td');
var index = $(this).closest('tr');
var table = $(this).closest('table');
$(table).find('tr td:nth-child(' + index + ') input[type=checkbox]').not(this).prop('disabled', this.checked);
```